# Except open URL BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have function that does request and gets page by URL:

```
def openUrl(similar_url):
    print("Open URL: " + similar_url)

    try:
        req = urllib.request.Request(similar_url)
        return urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print("HTTP Response: " + str(e.code))
```

I call this function from another:

```
def get(url):

    content = openUrl(url);

try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
except:
    pass

   for url in urls:
       get(url)
```

Problem is that if I get exception in `openUrl` then I get erro in `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")`, because I try to get empty content.

How can I except skip this iteration when error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return *WHAT YOU WANT*` inside exception block

```
try:
    req = urllib.request.Request(similar_url)
    return urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print("HTTP Response: " + str(e.code))
    return None # or return ""
```

and you can call like this

```
def get(url):
    try:
        content = openUrl(url) # remove semicolon
    except:
        pass
    else:
        if contents is not None:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
```